# How to loop over an array and count the number of movies that an actor has been in

Tags: php, arrays

I need to write a php script that will loop over the array and display the actors present in the

array in alphabetical order and the number of movies that they have appeared in:

```
$movies = array (
"horror"=>array (
  "Paranormal Activity"=> array (
      "Katie Featherston",
      "Kathryn Newton"
  ),
  "The Ring"=> array (
      "Naomi Watts",
      "Brian Cox"
  ),
  "Sleepy Hollow"=> array(
      "Johnny Depp",
      "Christina Ricci"
   )
),
"action" => array (
    "The Tourist"=> array (
        "Johnny Depp",
        "Angelina Jolie"
    ),
    "Public Enemies"=> array (
        "Johnny Depp",
        "Christian Bale"
    ),
    "The Dark Knight Rises"=> array (
        "Christian Bale",
        "Tom Hardy"
    ),
    "Salt"=> array (
        "Angelina Jolie"
    )
),
"thriller"=> array (
    "Inception"=> array(
        "Leornardio Dicaprio",
        "Tom Hardy"
    ),
    "Changeling" => array(
        "Angelina Jolie"
    ),
    "The Game"=> array(
        "Michael Douglas",
        "Sean Penn"
    )
 )
);
```

It should look like:

`Angelina Jolie (3)` and so on...

Comment: this is just an array, where are your attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood what you want to do, you need to reconstruct the array, a basic way to do this is :

(im not sure this is the best method, did it in 5mins)

```
$results = array();

foreach($movies as $cat => $films)
{
    foreach( $films as $film => $actors)
    {
        foreach($actors as $actor)
        {
            if(!isset($results[$actor]))
            {
                $results[$actor] = array();
            }
            $results[$actor][] = array('cat' => $cat, 'title' => $film);
        }
     }
}

ksort($results);

foreach($results as $actor => $films)
{
    $films_count = count($films);

    echo '- '.$actor.' ('.$films_count.')<br/>';
}
```

which will return :

```
- Angelina Jolie (3)
- Brian Cox (1)
- Christian Bale (2)
- Christina Ricci (1)
- Johnny Depp (3)
- Kathryn Newton (1)
- Katie Featherston (1)
- Leornardio Dicaprio (1)
- Michael Douglas (1)
- Naomi Watts (1)
- Sean Penn (1)
- Tom Hardy (2)
```

**EDIT : Sorry, forgot to sort it, done :) (added details on actors (films and cats of films))**

Comment: Is there a way to sort the actor's first names alphabetically? Like angelina first then brian then christian? But besides that it works great thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This can be also simplified by using walking in array recursively, then using `array_count_values()`

```
$movies = array ("horror"=>array ( "Paranormal Activity"=> array ( "Katie Featherston", "Kathryn Newton" ), "The Ring"=> array ( "Naomi Watts", "Brian Cox" ), "Sleepy Hollow"=> array( "Johnny Depp", "Christina Ricci" )),"action" => array ( "The Tourist"=> array ( "Johnny Depp", "Angelina Jolie" ), "Public Enemies"=> array ( "Johnny Depp", "Christian Bale" ), "The Dark Knight Rises"=> array ( "Christian Bale", "Tom Hardy" ), "Salt"=> array ( "Angelina Jolie" )),"thriller"=> array ( "Inception"=> array( "Leornardio Dicaprio", "Tom Hardy" ), "Changeling" => array( "Angelina Jolie" ), "The Game"=> array( "Michael Douglas", "Sean Penn" ) ));
$actors = array();
array_walk_recursive($movies, function($val) use (&$actors){
    $actors[] = $val;
});

$count = array_count_values($actors);
ksort($count);
foreach ($count as $actor_name => $appearances) {
    echo "$actor_name ($appearances) <br/>";
}
```

[Sample Out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/adrNSi)